# awaited promise not waiting for resolve() before contuining

Tags: javascript, node.js, tcpclient

I'm making a pretty simple game within node.js. within my TCP client I have a async function that returns a promise, the promise resolves when the socket receives the information and then closes. My problem is: when I await the function, the program moves on before it resolves example below:

```
async GetPlayers(player) {
    return new Promise(resolve =>{
        var net = require('net');
        const client  = new net.Socket();
    
        client.connect({
          port:this.port,
          host:this.IpAdress
        });
        
        client.on('error',function(error){
            console.log('Error : ' + error);
          });
          
        client.on('connect',function(){
        client.write("sendPlayersToMePls: "+ JSON.stringify(player)+"\n");
          var address = client.address();
          var port = address.port;
          var family = address.family;
          var ipaddr = address.address;
          
        });
        client.on('data',function(data){
            //
            var data2 = data.toString();
            if(data2.startsWith("hereAreYourPlayers: ")){
            if(Config.Verbose)console.log("data = "+data2);
            var players2 = data2.slice(20);
            var obj = JSON.parse(players2);
            that.FileSystem.allPlayers = obj.players;
            that.FileSystem.TickCount= parseInt(obj.turnCount);
            resolve(obj);
            client.end();
        }

    });
}

//to call it i am using the following
async UpdateMapStatuses(player){
        
        this.SetCurrentMap();
        const players = await GetPlayers(player);
        return new Promise(resolve => {
        //the program starts exectuing this before "players" has been defined
        //code that uses "players"
        }

}
```

Comment: the `UpdateMapStatuses()` function already returns a promise - why are your returning a promise of a promise?

Comment: what does `console.log("data = "+data2)` output? assuming it ouputs anything

Comment: @JaromandaX that makes sense, but it doesn't make sense to return that promise. it would make more sense to await that execution and return the result. But as you point out - we have no idea what the intent is.

Comment: Here's a thought ... the code looks wrong ... shouldn't it be `async function GetPlayers(player) {` and `async function UpdateMapStatuses(player){` - as written, this code won't even parse will it?

Comment: Thank you for your comments, you helped me diagnose the problem, I did resolve the inefficient code that you were talking about. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try converting your `client.on` callbacks to arrow functions and see if that helps. For example:

```
async GetPlayers(player) {
    return new Promise((resolve) =>{
        var net = require('net');
        const client  = new net.Socket();
    
        client.connect({
          port:this.port,
          host:this.IpAdress
        });
        
        client.on('error', (error) => {
            console.log('Error : ' + error);
          });
          
        client.on('connect', () => {
          client.write("sendPlayersToMePls: "+ JSON.stringify(player)+"\n");
          var address = client.address();
          var port = address.port;
          var family = address.family;
          var ipaddr = address.address;
          
        });
        client.on('data', (data) => {
            //
            var data2 = data.toString();
            if(data2.startsWith("hereAreYourPlayers: ")){
            if(Config.Verbose)console.log("data = "+data2);
            var players2 = data2.slice(20);
            var obj = JSON.parse(players2);
            that.FileSystem.allPlayers = obj.players;
            that.FileSystem.TickCount= parseInt(obj.turnCount);
            resolve(obj);
            client.end();
        }
```

Comment: Hey, just wanted to clarify, changing the functions to arrow functions did fix this problem, but there was another place in the code that had the same problem that i forgot to change, thus producing the same error, and i didn't notice where it had fired from had changed. Thank you for your help, I have marked your answer as accepted.

Comment: @AuthoredEntropy - Changing these particular functions to arrow functions does not look to me like it would make any difference.  There is no use of `this` in these arrow functions, therefore they would perform the same one way or the other.  Perhaps that was the case in the other function the OP mentions that is not shown in the question or the answer.  As it stands, this answer is very misleading because changing these functions to arrow functions does not fix anything.